# Average Logins per day SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, logging

I have a users table in MSSQL and i want to find out the average number of logins for all users per day?

I am thinking something with division but not entirely sure
the USER table looks like this

```
  [ID]
  ,[APPLICATION_ID]
  ,[LOGIN_NAME]
  ,[EMAIL]
  ,[MOBILE_PHONE1]
  ,[MOBILE_PHONE2]
  ,[TITLE]
  ,[FIRST_NAME]
  ,[LAST_NAME]
  ,[BIRTHDAY]
  ,[ADDRESS1]
  ,[ADDRESS2]
  ,[CITY]
  ,[COUNTRY_ID]
  ,[POSTAL_CODE]
  ,[PO_BOX]
  ,[HOME_PHONE]
  ,[OFFICE_PHONE]
  ,[FAX]
  ,[REMARKS]
  ,[DISPLAY_NAME]
  ,[MAIDEN_NAME]
  ,[ADDRESS3]
  ,[ADDRESS4]
  ,[KEYWORD1]
  ,[KEYWORD2]
  ,[KEYWORD3]
  ,[KEYWORD4]
  ,[CREATED_BY]
  ,[CREATED_ON]
  ,[MODIFIED_BY]
  ,[MODIFIED_ON]
  ,[DELETED]
  ,[DELETED_BY]
  ,[DELETED_ON]
  ,[VERSION]
  ,[IDENTIFICATION_NO]
  ,[GENDER_REFERENCE_ID]
  ,[IDENTIFICATION_REFERENCE_ID]
  ,[registration_date]
  ,[contact_person]
  ,[contact_email]
  ,[alternative_email]
  ,[electron_card_number]
  ,[LAST_LOGIN]
  ,[LAST_SUCCESSFUL_LOGIN]
  ,[LAST_UNSUCCESSFUL_LOGIN]
```

Answer (score 3):

From the table you provide, there is no way of calculating an average. To do this, you would need an historical record of user logins.

Answer (score 2):

There is nowhere in that table that tracks when a user has logged in, other than the last time.  You need a separarte table to record all logins, then you can calculate the average number per day.

Comment: Yes there is. What there isn't is anything that tracks the number of logins.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: I only see last_login, last_succesful_login and last_uncessful_login? How would you then know how many times the user has logged in?

Comment: Last_login is WHEN a login occured, isn't it? I agree it's useless for calculating an average.